# Migrating, but still getting crash on 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Realm, 1th thing
    {
        RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
        config.schemaVersion = 2;
        config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

        };
        config.objectClasses = @[[User class], [UsersMenuItem class]];
        [RLMRealm migrateRealm:config];
    }

    ...
}
```

I did add a property to the user object, the docu says the new realm should automigrate, but i get a crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'User' due to the following errors:
- Property 'realtedMenuItems' has been added to latest object model.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1838ad900 0x182f1bf80 0x10015db3c 0x10014aa60 0x100149a70 0x100116500 0x1000a6488 0x1000f1664 0x1885a00c0 0x18859fcc4 0x100039568 0x188615704 0x188844130 0x1888484b8 0x1888455c0 0x184e63790 0x184e63b10 0x183864efc 0x183864990 0x183862690 0x183791680 0x18860e580 0x188608d90 0x1000b7430 0x1833328b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Version: 0.95

Note: When i updated to 0.96 i get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 3.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of data stored in the realm at this point? Because you can do a clean and reset the simulator to fix this if you're just testing.

Comment: well i need the migration to perform on an existing app update :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding

```
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
```

solved the issue, although not sure why

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Realm
    {
        RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
        config.schemaVersion = 4;
        config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

        };
        NSError * error = [RLMRealm migrateRealm:config];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error migrating realm %@", error);
        }
        [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`RLMRealmConfiguration` acts as value object. Modifications applied to it, don't automatically take effect to the `defaultConfiguration`. You can only retrieve a copy of it. That means you have to user the setter to share you modifications back.

Comment: so to call [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config]; ? is that right? should this be done before, or after migrate?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The migrate method uses the provided configuration, while the `defaultRealm` uses the default configuration. But you don't necessarily have to use the migrate method at all. If you don't call it, your Realm will be migrated implicitly later when creating the first Realm instance.

Comment: nope, it crashed without using migrateRealm with the exception that i should migrate... so i do the above, with adding setDefaultConfiguration and it works

Comment: But you were not modifying the default configuration before and setting a migration block and a new schema version?