# 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required due to the following errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, realm

When i debug the app, i add a new property (@property NSString *haha;),but it show the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required due to the following errors: 
- Property 'haha' has been added to latest object model.'
```

But when i add the ignoredProperties, it works well:

```
+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties {
    return @[@"thead"];
}
```

Why? Thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242901/migrating-but-still-getting-crash-on-rlmexception-reason-migration-is-requ?rq=1

Comment: are you useing core data .

Comment: @balkaransingh Yep

Answer (score 5):

When your app is live / launched you need to do migration when changing your db model. You can refer to Realm's [migration docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations)

Meanwhile I believe you're still in the process of developing your app. You can just delete / uninstall from your simulator or device and rerun your code

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to delete the app and reinstall it to reflect the changes to your Realm objects.

Comment: migration is an option .. this is just workaround ... though this would work too :)

Comment: True, but from the description, it appears the app is being actively developed at the moment. Easier to reload than migrate IMO. But you are right that a migration is necessary for production release if this is a new version.

Comment: yes .. as its in development stage, its ok to remove app and install once again ..